# Why is my MySql Server connection string not working?

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, connection-string

I'm using Visual Wev Developer 2012 and trying to connect to MySql Server on a shared hosting site.  My connection string looks like this:

```
 Server="myserverAddress";Port="3306";Database="myDatabaseName";uid="myUserName";Pwd="myPassword"
```

HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.

I've tried with and without the quotes.  What am i doing wrong here?  I would really appreciate any help with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my project was using the default database (SQL Express) even though I didn’t have a connection string pointing to it.  The EF uses convention to attach the default database if you don’t specify by using a constructor like this:

```
 public class BloggingContext : DbContext
```

{

```
public BloggingContext()

    : base("BloggingDatabase")

{

}
```

}

Then this:

```
 <configuration>

   <connectionStrings>

<add name="BloggingCompactDatabase"

     providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0"

     connectionString="Data Source=Blogging.sdf"/>

   </connectionStrings>

 </configuration>
```

I found it all here…
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592674.aspx.